# Simple NEST search not returning results

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Here is my Cat class:

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my main program where I add a cat to the index and do a simple search:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
    settings.SetDefaultIndex("mdu-test");
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var cat = new Cat
    {
        Id = "1",
        Name = "Martijn",
    };
    var index = client.Index(cat);

    var searchResults = client.Search<Cat>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Query(q => q
           .Term(p => p.Name, "Martijn")
        )
    );

    Cat firstCat = searchResults.Documents.ToList()[0];
}
```

Using Curl I can see the document is added, but nothing is returned by my code. The funny thing is that I'm sure I had the same code working earlier. Any help with the solution or debugging would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query), which is not analyzed- meaning it will only find exact matches (case-sensitive).  I'm assuming you are using the [standard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer) analyzer (default) on your index, which is lower-casing all of your terms.

If you do want exact matches, then set `Name` to `not_analyzed` in your mapping, otherwise you probably want to use a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) instead, like so:

```cs
var searchResults = client.Search<Cat>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .OnField(p => p.Name)
            .Query("Martijn"))
    )
);
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you! Great explanation as well!

Comment: Hah I love that I'm used as an example cat here, eerie as I'm a huge cat person too :)